# What does calling a static methods inside the method itself mean in python

Tags: python, class, methods, static

I am watching a video on youtube about OOP. I encountered a type of syntax that I could not understand by my past information. The author calls the static method inside the method writing the argument at the beginning of the method's name. The method's function is to detect whether the passed number is an integer or not. The code is below:

```
class Dog:
    
    @staticmethod
    def is_integer(num):
        if isinstance(num,float):
            return num.is_integer()
        elif isinstance(num,int):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**My problem is this:**

What is the syntax behind `num.is_integer()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method definition is using [a method of `float` objects that has the same name](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=is_integer#float.is_integer), it's not calling itself. The `isinstance(num, float)` is making sure that it is actually used on a `float`, otherwise the program would throw an exception. If it would call itself, it would look more like `Dog.is_integer(num)`.

Comment: Therefore, I was confused with using the built-in method "is_integer" and our own static method's name :)